# Present ViewControllers Modally inside Parent ViewController UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have one main ViewController, which will render different views from other view controllers (mostly table views), by using `addChild:Vc` i can present and remove the child view, but the problem is it's a view hierarchy, so view layers will come over each other and every child view has a button which will dismiss itself and re-presents the previous view in view hierarchy. exactly like Navigation Bar back button.

[image]

So far what i have done is an UIViewController Extension which is:

```
func addChildVC(_ child: UIViewController,
                centerWith center: CGPoint? = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0),
                insertInView insertIn: UIView? = nil,
                transition: UIView.AnimationOptions? = [],
                completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
{
    self.addChild(child)

    if let center = center
    {
        child.view.center = center
    }

    if let insertIn = insertIn
    {
        insertIn.insertSubview(child.view, aboveSubview: insertIn.self)
    } else {
        self.view.addSubview(child.view)
    }

    child.didMove(toParent: self)
}

func removeChildVC()
{
    willMove(toParent: nil)
    view.removeFromSuperview()
    removeFromParent()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a navigation for the contained vc

**Step 1**

[image]

**Step 2** select the child vc and

[image]

**Step 3**

[image]

Now you can push and pop inside that child vc